# Extract specific fields information from Ansible kubernetes.core.k8s_info?

Tags: ansible

I have the following tasks, to gather the pods information, more exactly the `name` and `status`:

```yaml
- name: Get pod info
  kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
    api_version: v1
    kind: Pod
    label_selectors:
      - helmcharts.helm.cattle.io/chart = {{ item }}
      - job-name = helm-install-{{ item }}
    namespace: kube-system
  loop:
    - traefik
    - traefik-crd
  register: pod_info

- name: Debug
  ansible.builtin.debug:
    var: pod_info
```

Simplified output:

```json
ok: [apollo.lan] => {
    "pod_info": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "api_found": true,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "traefik",
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "apiVersion": "v1",
                        "kind": "Pod",
                        "metadata": {
                            "labels": {
                                "helmcharts.helm.cattle.io/chart": "traefik",
                                "job-name": "helm-install-traefik"
                            },
                            "name": "helm-install-traefik-fk7fb",
                            "namespace": "kube-system",
                            "resourceVersion": "2550"
                        },
                        "status": {
                            "phase": "Succeeded",
                            "podIP": "10.0.0.75"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                "api_found": true,
                "changed": false,
                "failed": false,
                "item": "traefik-crd",
                "resources": [
                    {
                        "apiVersion": "v1",
                        "kind": "Pod",
                        "metadata": {
                            "labels": {
                                "helmcharts.helm.cattle.io/chart": "traefik-crd",
                                "job-name": "helm-install-traefik-crd"
                            },
                            "name": "helm-install-traefik-crd-8p86c",
                            "namespace": "kube-system",
                            "resourceVersion": "2329"
                        },
                        "status": {
                            "phase": "Succeeded",
                            "podIP": "10.0.0.76"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "skipped": false
    }
}
```

I don't know how to extract and register the pod `name` as list, combined with a `when` condition that matches the `status` phase Succeeded.

I first tried to extract just the `metadata`, in order to drill down to `name`:

```yaml
- name: Set fact
  ansible.builtin.set_fact:
    variable: "{{ pod_info.results | json_query('metadata') }}"
```

Without success. I have a hard time determining the logic with a mix of lists and dictionaries, I even tried to look at `lookup('ansible.utils.to_paths', pod_info.results)` structure to see how I can pull the information.

Comment: This is not consultancy, what code have you already tried and what error is it producing for you? This is a super common question, so you'll the most benefit from this site by searching for [other similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+filter+json)

Comment: I understand this is not consultancy but I have a hard time determining the logic with a mix of lists and dictionaries. I looked at your search results and while this might be common to you, it is not for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary remark: I wouldn't do a loop to select the two pods you are looking for, I would rather use a `in`, like they are showing it [in the examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/k8s_info_module.html#examples).

So, your first task would become:

```yaml
- name: Get pod info
  kubernetes.core.k8s_info:
    api_version: v1
    kind: Pod
    label_selectors:
      - helmcharts.helm.cattle.io/chart in (traefik, traefik-crd)
      - job-name in (helm-install-traefik, helm-install-traefik-crd)
    namespace: kube-system
  register: pod_info
```

The reason for it is simple: by registering under a loop, you are complexifying the return, as Ansible will create a `results` list for each elements of the loop, when you won't have it with this way of requesting the Kubernetes pods information.

And so, with this, listing all the pods having the status phase `Succeeded` should be achievable with

- the [`selectattr` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.selectattr), in order to filter only the successful status phases
- the [`map` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) in order to extract only the names of the pods

```yaml
- debug:
    var: >-
      pod_info.resources 
        | selectattr('status.phase', '==', 'Succeeded')
        | map(attribute='metadata.name')
```